# Pin SliverAppBar to the bottom of container

Tags: flutter

How can I create a page layout where multiple `SliverAppBar`s, each followed by content (eg. a `Sliverlist`) not only Stack at the top like so:

[stacking slivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP1O2.jpg)

But also at the bottom, like so:

[bottom stacking slivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjUOT.jpg)

Additionally I should be able to click on an individual `SliverAppBar` and have that section scroll into view as much as possible.

My attempt works by placing a fake SliverAppBar (In red, to highlight my hack) at the bottom of my container whenever the scroll offset would be such that the actual `SliverAppBar` would go past that point. Furthermore I listen to click events on the `SliverAppBar`s and modify the scroll position to simulate the desired "opening" effect.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const BottomPinSliverAppBar());
}

class BottomPinSliverAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomPinSliverAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomPinSliverAppBar> createState() =>
      _BottomPinSliverAppBarState();
}

class _BottomPinSliverAppBarState extends State<BottomPinSliverAppBar> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  final GlobalKey _drawerKey = GlobalKey();
  bool _showBottomAppBar = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final RenderBox renderBox =
          _drawerKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy + 75;

      if (position >= _scrollController.position.viewportDimension &&
          !_showBottomAppBar) {
        setState(() {
          _showBottomAppBar = true;
        });
      } else if (position < _scrollController.position.viewportDimension &&
          _showBottomAppBar) {
        setState(() {
          _showBottomAppBar = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                actions: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                        _scrollController.animateTo(0,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text('Drawer 1'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                      height: 100.0,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 10,
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  key: _drawerKey,
                ),
              ),
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                actions: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      onTap: () {
                        final RenderBox renderBox = _drawerKey.currentContext!
                            .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                        debugPrint(
                            renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy.toString());
                        final position = _scrollController.offset +
                            renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy -
                            90;
                        _scrollController.animateTo(position,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                      },
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text('Drawer 2'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                      height: 100.0,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 10,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if (_showBottomAppBar) _buildBottomAppBar(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomAppBar() {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          final RenderBox renderBox =
              _drawerKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          debugPrint(renderBox.size.height.toString());
          final position = _scrollController.offset +
              renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy -
              90;
          _scrollController.animateTo(position,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.easeInOut);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 55,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text('Drawer 2'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This solution has obvious limitations:

- Adding multiple drawers would quickly bloat the if-else logic.
- A slight change to styling, or a different text-scaling factor would break my hardcoded pixel thresholds and make the effect jumpy and janky.
- I do not like having to add a postFrameCallback, it feels like I am diving too deep into the Flutter magic for a usecase that I hoped was not too complicated.

Hence my question, how can this solution be improved, and are there (hopefully) completely different approaches with the desired result?